# Bootstrap Submit button is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a Bootstrap Form, But Submit button is not working. When I click on button, its only clicked...but nothing happens.

Please Help.

```
<form role="form" name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Field 1 -->
    <div class="input-text form-group">
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="input-name form-control" placeholder="Full Name" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 2 -->
    <div class="input-email form-group">
        <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="input-email form-control" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 3 -->
    <div class="input-email form-group">
        <input type="text" name="contact_phone" class="input-phone form-control" placeholder="Phone" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 4 -->
    <div class="textarea-message form-group">
        <textarea name="contact_message" class="textarea-message hight-82 form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you have to set the attribute `action` of the `form`.

Comment: action is not a mandatory attribute.. are you using any javascripts/jquery?

Comment: what will be happend if no action is provided? - in this case nothing

Comment: @AdarshMohan that`s why i was not added action, because i will use php command in same page.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch Do you find any solution?? yet

Comment: @AnkitBhatnagar - add the php part which will be execute after submit!

Comment: @AnkitBhatnagar : The code you posted is working fine

Comment: I also had this issue, and I found out that I had two forms and two buttons in the same file! Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In a form you use input fields. Change `<button>` to `<input type='submit'>`

```
<form role="form" name="contactform" id="contactform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <!-- Field 1 -->
                                    <div class="input-text form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="input-name form-control" placeholder="Full Name" />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Field 2 -->
                                    <div class="input-email form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="input-email form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Field 3 -->
                                    <div class="input-email form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="contact_phone" class="input-phone form-control" placeholder="Phone" />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Field 4 -->
                                    <div class="textarea-message form-group">
                                        <textarea name="contact_message" class="textarea-message hight-82 form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="2"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                 <input type="submit" class="btn" value='Submit'>


                                </form>
```

WHen using POST you don't have to put action in your code. unless you want to post to another page.

Comment: type="submit" is not actually needed for the button to submit the form

Comment: there is no difference between `button` and `input` with type `submit`. Both will be submit the form.

Comment: and `type="submit"` is not requiared, as far as i know.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button button has this type by default, so yes, it is not requiared for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like everything is working fine.. i think you have made some mistakes in your scripts

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contactform').on('submit',function(){
    $('#result').html('submitted');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form role="form" name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Field 1 -->
    <div class="input-text form-group">
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="input-name form-control" placeholder="Full Name" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 2 -->
    <div class="input-email form-group">
        <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="input-email form-control" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 3 -->
    <div class="input-email form-group">
        <input type="text" name="contact_phone" class="input-phone form-control" placeholder="Phone" />
    </div>
    <!-- Field 4 -->
    <div class="textarea-message form-group">
        <textarea name="contact_message" class="textarea-message hight-82 form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```